MongoDB Aggregations: Why is $group slow with indexed string fields but not on date?
Setup
Imagine this document shape:
{
  dateString: "2024-10-31", // type string
  realDate: ISODate("2024-10-31"), // type date
}

Assume both fields are indexed separately.
Problem
If I create an aggregation with a $match stage followed by a $group stage, the type of the queried field makes a difference:

on dateString, the $group stage causes IXSCAN -> FETCH -> GROUP actions (as seen in explain). This is considerably slower than querying on realDate.
on realDate, the $group stage causes only IXSCAN -> PROJECTION_COVERED <-- This is magnitudes faster (on 500k records: 9 ms vs. 30 sec+)

Any ideas why that is and how to solve this?

Aggregations:
// This aggregation is slow despite the string field being indexed.
[
  {
    $match: {
      dateString: {
        $gte: "2024-10-01",
        $lte: "2024-10-31"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dateString",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]

// This aggregation is fast because it's on an indexed date field.
[
  {
    $match: {
      realDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2024-10-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2024-10-31")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $month: "$realDate"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]

Explain plan:
{
    "explainVersion": "2",
    "queryPlanner": {
        "namespace": "autoixpert.reports",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "completionDate": {
                        "$lte": "2024-10-31"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "completionDate": {
                        "$gte": "2024-10-01"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "collation": {
            "locale": "de",
            "caseLevel": false,
            "caseFirst": "off",
            "strength": 3,
            "numericOrdering": false,
            "alternate": "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable": "punct",
            "normalization": false,
            "backwards": false,
            "version": "57.1"
        },
        "queryHash": "B08363F9",
        "planCacheKey": "B727189F",
        "optimizedPipeline": true,
        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
        "winningPlan": {
            "queryPlan": {
                "stage": "GROUP",
                "planNodeId": 4,
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "FETCH",
                    "planNodeId": 2,
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "IXSCAN",
                        "planNodeId": 1,
                        "keyPattern": { "completionDate": 1 },
                        "indexName": "completionDate_1",
                        "collation": {
                            "locale": "de",
                            "caseLevel": false,
                            "caseFirst": "off",
                            "strength": 3,
                            "numericOrdering": false,
                            "alternate": "non-ignorable",
                            "maxVariable": "punct",
                            "normalization": false,
                            "backwards": false,
                            "version": "57.1"
                        },
                        "isMultiKey": false,
                        "multiKeyPaths": {
                            "completionDate": []
                        },
                        "isUnique": false,
                        "isSparse": false,
                        "isPartial": false,
                        "indexVersion": 2,
                        "direction": "forward",
                        "indexBounds": {
                            "completionDate": [
                                "[CollationKey(0x1612161a050e1412050e1214010e010e), CollationKey(0x1612161a050e1412050e1814010e010e)]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "slotBasedPlan": {
                "slots": "$$RESULT=s19 env: { s4 = 1730549863726 (NOW), s5 = Collator({\"locale\" : \"de\", \"caseLevel\" : false, \"caseFirst\" : \"off\", \"strength\" : 3, \"numericOrdering\" : false, \"alternate\" : \"non-ignorable\", \"maxVariable\" : \"punct\", \"normalization\" : false, \"backwards\" : false, \"version\" : \"57.1\"}) (collator), s7 = KS(3C1612161A050E1412050E1214010E010E000104), s1 = TimeZoneDatabase(Africa/Nairobi...Asia/Kolkata) (timeZoneDB), s8 = KS(3C1612161A050E1412050E1814010E010E00FE04), s3 = Timestamp(1730549861, 1) (CLUSTER_TIME), s2 = Nothing (SEARCH_META), s12 = {\"completionDate\" : 1} }",
                "stages": "[4] project [s19 = newBsonObj(\"_id\", s16, \"count\", s17)] \n[4] group [s16] [s17 = sum(1)] spillSlots[s18] mergingExprs[sum(s18)] s5 \n[4] project [s16 = (s15 ?: null)] \n[2] nlj inner [] [s6, s9, s10, s11, s12] \n    left \n        [1] cfilter {(exists(s7) && exists(s8))} \n        [1] ixseek s7 s8 s11 s6 s9 s10 [] @\"474a8370-3457-4ceb-b673-80c0b5ce9203\" @\"completionDate_1\" true \n    right \n        [2] limit 1ll \n        [2] seek s6 s13 s14 s9 s10 s11 s12 [s15 = completionDate] @\"474a8370-3457-4ceb-b673-80c0b5ce9203\" true false \n"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": []
    },
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": 27,
        "executionTimeMillis": 5,
        "totalKeysExamined": 221,
        "totalDocsExamined": 221,
        "executionStages": {
            "stage": "project",
            "planNodeId": 4,
            "nReturned": 27,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "opens": 1,
            "closes": 1,
            "saveState": 0,
            "restoreState": 0,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "projections": {
                "19": "newBsonObj(\"_id\", s16, \"count\", s17) "
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "group",
                "planNodeId": 4,
                "nReturned": 27,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "opens": 1,
                "closes": 1,
                "saveState": 0,
                "restoreState": 0,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "groupBySlots": [16],
                "expressions": {
                    "17": "sum(1) ",
                    "initExprs": { "17": null }
                },
                "mergingExprs": { "18": "sum(s18) " },
                "usedDisk": false,
                "spills": 0,
                "spilledRecords": 0,
                "spilledDataStorageSize": 0,
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "project",
                    "planNodeId": 4,
                    "nReturned": 221,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                    "opens": 1,
                    "closes": 1,
                    "saveState": 0,
                    "restoreState": 0,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "projections": {
                        "16": "(s15 ?: null) "
                    },
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "nlj",
                        "planNodeId": 2,
                        "nReturned": 221,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                        "opens": 1,
                        "closes": 1,
                        "saveState": 0,
                        "restoreState": 0,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "totalDocsExamined": 221,
                        "totalKeysExamined": 221,
                        "collectionScans": 0,
                        "collectionSeeks": 221,
                        "indexScans": 0,
                        "indexSeeks": 1,
                        "indexesUsed": ["completionDate_1"],
                        "innerOpens": 221,
                        "innerCloses": 1,
                        "outerProjects": [],
                        "outerCorrelated": [6, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                        "outerStage": {
                            "stage": "cfilter",
                            "planNodeId": 1,
                            "nReturned": 221,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                            "opens": 1,
                            "closes": 1,
                            "saveState": 0,
                            "restoreState": 0,
                            "isEOF": 1,
                            "numTested": 1,
                            "filter": "(exists(s7) && exists(s8)) ",
                            "inputStage": {
                                "stage": "ixseek",
                                "planNodeId": 1,
                                "nReturned": 221,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                                "opens": 1,
                                "closes": 1,
                                "saveState": 0,
                                "restoreState": 0,
                                "isEOF": 1,
                                "indexName": "completionDate_1",
                                "keysExamined": 221,
                                "seeks": 1,
                                "numReads": 222,
                                "indexKeySlot": 11,
                                "recordIdSlot": 6,
                                "snapshotIdSlot": 9,
                                "indexIdentSlot": 10,
                                "outputSlots": [],
                                "indexKeysToInclude": "00000000000000000000000000000000",
                                "seekKeyLow": "s7 ",
                                "seekKeyHigh": "s8 "
                            }
                        },
                        "innerStage": {
                            "stage": "limit",
                            "planNodeId": 2,
                            "nReturned": 221,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                            "opens": 221,
                            "closes": 1,
                            "saveState": 0,
                            "restoreState": 0,
                            "isEOF": 1,
                            "limit": 1,
                            "inputStage": {
                                "stage": "seek",
                                "planNodeId": 2,
                                "nReturned": 221,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                                "opens": 221,
                                "closes": 1,
                                "saveState": 0,
                                "restoreState": 0,
                                "isEOF": 0,
                                "numReads": 221,
                                "recordSlot": 13,
                                "recordIdSlot": 14,
                                "seekKeySlot": 6,
                                "snapshotIdSlot": 9,
                                "indexIdentSlot": 10,
                                "indexKeySlot": 11,
                                "indexKeyPatternSlot": 12,
                                "fields": ["completionDate"],
                                "outputSlots": [15]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "command": {
        "aggregate": "reports",
        "pipeline": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "completionDate": {
                        "$gte": "2024-10-01",
                        "$lte": "2024-10-31"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$completionDate",
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {},
        "collation": { "locale": "de" },
        "maxTimeMS": 60000,
        "$db": "autoixpert"
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "795d0985cbad",
        "port": 27017,
        "version": "7.0.11",
        "gitVersion": "f451220f0df2b9dfe073f1521837f8ec5c208a8c"
    },
    "serverParameters": {
        "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
        "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
        "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
        "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
        "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
        "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
        "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
        "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
        "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeRestricted"
    },
    "ok": 1,
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": {
            "$timestamp": "7432655057092345857"
        },
        "signature": {
            "hash": "HYWsaU9s9ulyEsmOYYHunIajzyM=",
            "keyId": {
                "low": 7,
                "high": 1729592506,
                "unsigned": false
            }
        }
    },
    "operationTime": {
        "$timestamp": "7432655057092345857"
    }
}



I doubt that the 2 pipelines are functionally equivalent. The first one you are grouping by dates, which is possible to have 31 groupings in 2024 Oct while the 2nd one is grouping by just month so there is only 1 grouping.

Also consider the speed of String comparison vs Date comparison. So $gte: "2024-10-01", $lte: "2024-10-31" is already going to be significantly slower, even with an index. Because it's still string comparisons. Date comparisons are effectively like comparing Integers or Floats.

@aneroid Even if string comparison is slower, that shouldn't account for such a large delay on the matching records of only about 25,000.

@ray even 31 groups should be feasable for MongoDB. The core issue seems to be that a FETCH is triggered, which would be very slow on 25,000 records. Any ideas why that happens although the field dateString is covered by an index?

@Mark can you attach the 2 explain plans then?

Testing these locally, I see both using PROJECTION_COVERED, do you have a reproducer you can share?

Sure, I added the explain plan to the question.

I reproduced the issue on a fresh database. The problem only arises when using an index with a collation ("de" for German in our case). The aggregation is using the same collation as the index, hence the IXSCAN in the first step. I just don't understand why the PROJECTION_COVERED is not triggered. It is however triggered on the index on the realDate of type date if it has a collation.

Ah, that explains it.  A collation changes how string data is stored in an index, so a collated index cannot be used to cover a query of a string field.  The realDate query is covered because the date data is unaffected since collations only impact string data.

Hi Joe, I can't quite see why that is, though. It's enough for filtering, so why should it not be enough for grouping?
